# How can i run Redis raw commands in Java Lettuce?

Tags: java, redis, lettuce

I am building a Java application using lettuce as a Redis client.

One of the requirements is to run the redis commands from inside the application as i would run them from the command line redis-cli 
so instead of writing the implemented API method:

```
commands.set("key", "value");
```

I enter the actual raw command:

```
SET key value
```

and the command would run on the server.
For example is there a method in the letuce api simmilar to this?

```
commands.runrawcommand("SET key value");
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

That won't entirely work. Redis commands as used in a cli require parsing and result processing. Take a look at the wiki explaining [Custom commands](https://github.com/mp911de/lettuce/wiki/Custom-commands%2C-outputs-and-command-mechanics).

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it is possible and `@mp911de's answer` is not correct, although it has the correct reference link : [Custom Commands](https://lettuce.io/core/release/reference/#_custom_commands)

You can easily create an `interface` and by `extending` following `io.lettuce.core.dynamic.Commands` `interface` you can define your raw command as below:

```
public interface CustomCommands extends Commands {

    @Command("FCALL :functionName :keysCount :jobsKey :inboxRef :jobsRef :jobIdentity :frwrdMsg ")
    Object fcall_responseJob(@Param("functionName") byte[] functionName, @Param("keysCount") Integer keysCount,
                 @Param("jobsKey") byte[] jobsKey, @Param("inboxRef") byte[] inboxRef,
                 @Param("jobsRef") byte[] jobsRef, @Param("jobIdentity") byte[] jobIdentity,
                 @Param("frwrdMsg") byte[] frwrdMsg);

}
```

And for your usecase it could be like:

```
@Command("SET :key :value")
Object custom_set(@Param("key") String key, Param("value") String value);
```

Then you can call it as below:

```
   RedisCommandFactory factory = new RedisCommandFactory(connection);
   CustomCommands commands = factory.getCommands(CustomCommands.class);
   Object obj = commands.csustom_set("YOUR_KEY".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8),
                                     "YOUR_VALUE".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```